# Using hyphen(-) in the url without encoding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

Trying to make a request using the angular js $resource but it is encoding the url for making a request.

Request url `http://example.com/oabc/access-token`

and the code is

```
$resource(url).save(data).$promise.then(success, error);
```

But it makes a request to

```
http://example.com/oabc/access%C2%ADtoken
```

which is obviously not found because **-** is encoded to **%C2%AD**.

**Question:-** So how could I prevent this and call to the above mentioned url ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Is this some special unicode hyphen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That hyphen is not a U+002D HYPHEN MINUS "-", it's a U+00AD SOFT HYPHEN, which encodes to `C2 AD` in UTF-8. Fix the character used.

Comment: Why does a soft hyphen (U+00AD) get encoded as `%C2%AD` ? The character U+00C2—capital A circumflex, or “A-hat”, Â—is completely unrelated!

Comment: The Unicode code point U+00AD gets encoded to the ***byte sequence*** `C2AD` in the *UTF-8 encoding*. That's how it works. Unicode code points don't map directly to the same bytes in UTF-8.